# Apache Alias and multiple versions of codebase

Tags: php, apache, api, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am trying to run a versioned API from separate directories outside my Apache doc root.

My current approach is to try this with the [Alias directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html):

```
Alias /api/v1.2/ /var/www/api-v1.2/
Alias /api/v1.1/ /var/www/api-v1.1/
```

This is working fine, however I am using a PHP framework (Codeigniter) that uses mod_rewrite to route all requests to my index.php front controller:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?$1 [L]
```

I can access actual files via the URL, and the alias directive works fine. When I access a URL that the system means to rewrite, the request is served from the doc root.

How can I get my CI application to follow the Alias rules while still routing traffic to each respective front controller?

**EDIT:** to be clear, I have 3 separate versions of my CI codebase: 1 in the Apache doc root, and 2 others in each aliased directory. I want to route requests to the correct version of the codebase based on the URL (defaulting to the doc root if no Alias is matched).

```
/var/www/html (doc root)
/var/www/api-v1.2
/var/www/api-v1.1
```

Comment: Did you tried routing? http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: @Nil'z I cannot use CI's routing features, as I want to run different versions of my application from separate versions of the codebase (different PHP files). Each version must be completely separate and isolated from the others.

Comment: If you have different _versions_ of your app, you should have different document roots as well IMHO.

Comment: @CBroe different document roots meaning using Apache virtual hosts? Is that possible with the same hostname but different URL sub directories? If you mean different PHP files in different directories on the filesystem, then that is exactly what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Not necessarily (although using different subdomains for different API versions instead of specifying the version through the URL path would be another option). But if the shared DOCUMENT_ROOT is your main problem in using the standard CI routing, then you could try and manipulate that value for each directory.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Because the Alias directive in Apache is independent to Mod_rewrite. Alias is applied first. There should be nothing standing in your way (but perhaps some misconception about CI which is not that well with webserver integration but this should be no problem here).

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem is that you aren't preventing your initial `.htaccess` from rewriting the folders.

You will need 3 `.htaccess` files, one in the root and one in each of the v1.1 and v1.2 folders.

Root (docroot):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|api/v1.1|api/v1.2)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

The important line being the last `RewriteCond` where it tells apache to ignore the api folders.

api-v1.1 folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /api/v1.1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

api-v1.2 folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /api/v1.2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

The important lines being `RewriteBase`. This tells apache the directory we're working in and will process the rewrites based on its designation.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Both your version and my version of the .htaccess rules work for redirecting requests to the `index.php` front controller, however I cannot get this to work and respect the `alias` rules and serve code from the proper directories.

Comment: Are you trying to serve CI content (e.g. do you have a third CI install in the root directory?) or will you only be serving from either v1.1 or v1.2?

Comment: yes I have 3 total CI codebases, one in the apache doc root, and 2 served from the API aliases. OP updated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - but it is still a little off. With the given rules, I can only access the correct codebase at the following URL: `http://host.com/api/v1.2/api/v1.2/endpoint?param=val` Any ideas on how to avoid the double path? Hitting the desired URL only returns an Apache 404, "File does not exist"

Comment: Do you have any other routing in place? And is the folder structure such that the root/default is in `/var/www` and the api stuff is a subfolder e.g. `/var/www/api-v1.2`?

Comment: No - no other routing in place. And no, the api directories are outside the web root.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think this is pretty straightforward. You want to make sure the set of rewrite conditions (RewriteCond) are not matched in one case - when they start with "/api" or "api" - so they don't fire the rewrite rule.

So, just add this line at the top of the CodeIgniter rewrite conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^(/)?api)
```

That will prevent that set of conditions from being matched when your request URI (the part after the "http://example.com/") starts with /api or api.  Any request URI that doesn't match /api or api WILL fire the CodeIgniter rules.

There are two secrets to mod_rewrite:
1) It breaks up the incoming request into tokens: the HTTP_HOST(e.g. "http://example.com"), the REQUEST_URI (the part after the http://example.com - like say, /index.php) and optional QUERY_STRING (the part after a ? in "http//example.com/index.php?test=3").

2) Then you can use perl regular expressions to match those tokens and rewrite the url to point to a resource or really, do any number of URL rewrites or substitutions.

References:
1) Rewrite tutorial: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html 
2) Rewrite reference: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html 
3) Regular expression cheat sheet: http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/